# Pegar ID do elemento clicado

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma DIV e essa DIV tem alguns checkbox com ID e eu quero saber como pego o id do checkbox clicado.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="0" value="false" name="ckb0">
    <label for="0">TESTE</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="false" name="ckb1">
    <label for="1">Posso escolher essa</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="false" name="ckb2">
    <label for="2">Essa também</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="false" name="ckb3">
    <label for="3">E essa</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="false" name="ckb4">
    <label for="4">este tambem</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie um `event handler` e use `$(this).attr("id")`. O código abaixo irá pegar os cliques em todos os `checkbox` dentro da `div #resposta`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#resposta").find("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resposta" class="box-resposta">
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="0" value="false" name="ckb0">
      <label for="0">TESTE</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="false" name="ckb1">
      <label for="1">Posso escolher essa</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="false" name="ckb2">
      <label for="2">Essa também</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="false" name="ckb3">
      <label for="3">E essa</label>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="false" name="ckb4">
      <label for="4">este tambem</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Documentação jQuery:**

[Função .attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)
[Função .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.